# How to upgrade/update a C application with newer version

Tags: c, gcc

My application is in C. I have to add a functionality in my application so that it should be able to upgrade itself according to the latest version. More specifically it should recognize if any newer version is found and get updated with that newer version (according to 
the new executable). There may be situations like schema of database may get changed in the newer version. So what provision can I give in my code so that it can recognize the new executable and upgrade itself according to that?

Platform: linux, gcc compiler

Comment: If it's Linux updates should come via your distro's package management system. Letting random users write to the binaries of system-wide applications is asking for trouble.

Comment: In general for the database schema part you need to write something to a) spot when the schema is older than what the application is looking for and b) apply the new schema, converting any rows that aren't compatible (via sensible default/calculated values for new fields and removing old fields) - that's a huge problem though, but one which most ORM systems make easier to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can update your binary as proposed by @Joachim and @awoodland above.  While both are valid, I would err on the side of caution and simply get your package management tool to do the donkey work.  Reasons being security and more critically to resolve dependencies.  Unfortunately this requires you to maintain packages however given that you probably could get away with a deb file and an rpm file and cover the vast majority this is no biggy.

On the database upgrade side, create a SQL script that backup the db and one (or a series) to update it (adding the appropriate fields etc.)

Have your script create a database version table with the version number date and time of upgrade and the software revision number that performed the upgrade and whether it succeeded or not (anything you can think that is useful.  Also make sure it inserts a row into your version table every time you upgrade.

When you start your binary program get it to check the maximum version number against the expected db version to ensure that the binary is compatible with the database version else upgrade.

Extending this further you can upgrade between vastly different versions by having it loop through a set of upgrade scripts.  You should keep these as an embedded resource if you want to keep them safe(r) from prying eyes but this should resolve your problem.

Hope this helps, I haven't had my coffee yet but it may point to a solution.  Going a step further you could also create an upgrade log table to record how the upgrade went and if any problems were encoutered, to help in those situations that hopefully will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

How about it simply overwrites its own executable, then use [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to create a new process and [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) the new executable?

This is not very safe or reliable however, as has been noted. A better solution might be for the program to check a special location for an installer, preferably signed, that is downloaded and run. This installer than has to ask the user for permission to install itself. Much like the Firefox update on Windows.

Comment: The OP needs to update database schemas and what-not.

Comment: Ouch - what stops somebody else overwriting that executable with a "steal all my secrets" trojan?

Comment: @awoodland That is a risk all systems and applications have. Who's to say that Windows Update, or the Debian repositories, hasn't been compromised?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - the Debian repositories are signed at least. Anyway the point is that with both windows update and apt on Debian you need "super user" access to make any changes. For "when I run I download a new version" to be useful it needs *every user* to be able to overwrite it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the basic steps that i can follow to pick up the new executable and backup all the data that was not uploaded and then upgrade the application with new executable ...

Comment: @john: A simple first step would be to research upgrading via your Linux distribution package system, like RPM or dpkg.